# Fill SVG shape with another SVG shape

Tags: svg, shapes, fill

Is it possible to use one SVG shape as the fill of another shape?

Comment: how is this different than drawing an two SVG shapes, with one having positions inside other shape?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use an [SVG Pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns). See [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/pservers/pattern01.svg):

```svg
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="TrianglePattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
             viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
      <path d="M0,0 L7,0 L3.5,7 z" fill="red" stroke="blue" />
    </pattern> 
  </defs>

  <!-- The ellipse is filled using a triangle pattern paint server
       and stroked with black -->
  <ellipse fill="url(#TrianglePattern)" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"  
           cx="400" cy="200" rx="350" ry="150" />
</svg>
```

Note that:

- The `viewBox` of the `<pattern>` will clip what is drawn. (As seen in the example, the top stroke and top-left corner each triangle is slightly hidden.)
- When the `viewBox` is a different size from the `width` and `height` you are effectively scaling the size of the graphic(s) in your pattern. (The example scales the 7-unit-wide triangle in the pattern up by a factor of 10, such that only 7 of them—plus padding—are visible across the width of a 700-unit-wide ellipse.)